# How to change the wake up Button on the Motorola Droid Pro to be any keyboard key?

Tags: buttons, motorola-droid-pro

I really hate that the sleep/mute key button is the same that wakes up the phone; I would want to be able to wake it up by pressing any key on the phone. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a solution can be found among the answers of this related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/how-can-i-customize-the-actions-associated-with-my-moto-droids-hardware-buttons

Comment: Or possibly even this one http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/730/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-htc-incredible-phone-use-the-optical-joystick-button-to or this one http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/671/how-to-check-htc-desire-is-off-without-turning-it-on